# Delete form fields using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

Is it possible to write a Javascript function to delete form a field when somebody does not fill in the field?

```
<form id="myform">
<label for="q1" id="q1label">question 1</label>
<input type="text" id="q1" name="q1"/>
<label for="q2" id="q2label">question 2</label>
<input type="text" id="q2" name="q2"/>
<label for="q3" id="q3label">question 3</label>
<input type="text" id="q3" name="q3"/>
<input type="submit" value="Delete blank fields" onclick="return checkanddelete"/>
</form>
```

If somebody does not fill in question 2 for example, it deletes question 2 label and the field.

Comment: You mean, you do not want the form to be submitted but instead to have some fields deleted when the submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 3):

For jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkanddelete() {
    $('input').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.remove('#' + id);
            $.remove('#' + id + 'label');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

For JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkanddelete() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
{
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value.length == 0) {
        var id = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].id;
        (elem=document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        (elem=document.getElementById(id + 'label')).parentNode.removeChild(elem)
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Something like this?

Comment: Won't that give a reference error about `$` not being defined?

Comment: Thx for your reply. I will have a try.

Comment: user1667419, please reload as i've added plain JavaScript instead of jQuery :) (nnnnn, you too haha)

Comment: that will loop over every input field in the page, not that pretty. some event binding would be nice to

Comment: Willem, the javascript #2 should be in a function, same as the jquery #1; if done it's in an event. It's not that pretty, that's true, but for reference it should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery:

```
$("#myform :text").each(function(){
    if( !$.trim($(this).val()) )
        $(this).prev('label').andSelf().remove();
});
```

Comment: Please note that this only works with jQuery library, not plain-text JavaScript :)

Comment: Yeah you're right :) and that's why I added "With jquery" on top of my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want :

```
var inputToDelete = document.getElementById("q2");
if (inputToDelete.value == "") {
   var labelToDelete = document.getElementById("q2label");
   var parentNode = document.getElementById("myform");
   parentNode.removeChild(labelToDelete);
   parentNode.removeChild(inputToDelete);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using folloing function to remove element from document.

```
function removeElement(id)
{
    if(typeof id === "object")
        return id.parentNode.removeChild(id);
    else
        return (elem=document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

You can pass a dom element or element Id itself to delete .

Comment: djeezes, is everyone here blind or what ? "when somebody does not fill in the field", read the question will you.

Comment: Willem D'haeseleer ofcourse conditions needs to be putted to check if the field is not filled by used thn call function to remove.

Comment: instead of putting that in a comment you should put it in your code